# Linux commands equivalent to ovs add port with vlan

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, openvswitch, vlan

`ovs-vsctl add-port hostInterface hostveth tag=9`. This command adds hostveth to bridge and also the packets coming out of hostveth are tagged with vlan id 9. I'm looking for similar commands for linux bridge

My setup is

hostInterface(bridge) -> hostvethpair -> ns1vethpair(another namespace)
hostinterface and hostvethpair are is same default namespace but ns1vethpair in different namespace.

I want packets coming out of hostvethpair to be tagged with vlan id and these tagged packets should be sent to bridge. Im able to achieve this with ovs bridge using above command. Is there any command that can do the same in Linux bridge. If so, can you share an example?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the solution for what i'm looking for. It can be done via bridge vlan filtering rules. (bridge vlan add).